# Classifying customer churn

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, rapidminer, churn

For an academic project I have to analyse a customer database of an insurance company.
This insurance company would like to identify a couple things, first of all classifying customers who leave the company in order to make them some offers or such..
Then they also would like to know on which customers to make upselling or cross-selling, as well as finding risky customers, in terms of insurance claims.

So I am focusing on the customer cancellations as it seems the most important one.

The attributes provided by the insurance company are:

Bundled/Unbundled, Policy Status, Policy Type, Policy Combination, Issue Date, Effective Date, Maturity Date, Policy Duration, Loan Duration, Cancellation Date, Reason for cancellation, Total Premium, Splitter Premium, Partner ID, Agency ID, Country Agency, Zone ID, Agency potential, Sex Contractor, Birth Year Contractor, Job Contractor, Sex Insured, Job Insured, Birth Year Insured, Year Claim, Claim Status, Claim Provision, Claim Payments

The database is composed of ~200k records and there are many missing values for some attributes.
I started using Rapid Miner to mine the dataset.
I cleaned the dataset a bit, removing incoherent or wrong values.

I then tried applying decision trees, adding a new attribute derived from Policy Status (which can be issued,renewed or cancelled) called isCanceled, and using it as the label of the decision tree.
I tried changing **every single** parameter of the decision tree, but I either get a tree with only 1 leaf node and no splits, or some tree that is completely irrelevant since it has leaf nodes with almost the same number instances of the 2 classes.
This is getting really frustrating.

I'd like to know what the usual procedures to make churn analysis are, possibly using Rapid Miner..can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience most data mining or machine learning activities spend most of their time cleaning, tidying, formatting and understanding the data.

Assuming this has been done, then as long as there is a relationship between some or all of the attributes and the label to be predicted it will be possible to perform some sort of churn analysis.

There are lots of ways to determine this relationship of course but a quick way is to try one of the `Weight By` operators. This will output a set of weights for each attribute with those near 1 being potentially more predictive of the label.

If you determine there are attributes of value, you can use Decision Trees or another operator to build a model that can be used to predict. The attributes you have are a mix of nominal and numeric types so Decision Trees will work and anyway this operator is easier to visualize. The tricky part is getting the parameters right and the way to do this is to observe the performance of a model on unseen data as the parameters are varied. The `Loop Parameters` operator can help with this.